# I get the message ''could not find the task 'build'" when I try to start my C# code

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am new to C# and am learning using pluralsight

I have followed exactly what the tutorials are doing but have ran into a problem that the tutorial does not.

I have the simple ''Hello World'' program built when you make C# code via .Net

In Visual Studio Code, if go with Start Debugging or Start Without Debugging, the following error pops up

''could not find the task 'build'"

I then click on debug anyway then the following error shows up

launch:program dir \ < insert-project-name-here >.dll does not exist 
there is an option to open launch.json

the confusing thing is, the .dll file DOES exist...

Further, checking launch.json, I have the following:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "WARNING01": "*********************************************************************************",
      "WARNING02": "The C# extension was unable to automatically decode projects in the current",
      "WARNING03": "workspace to create a runnable launch.json file. A template launch.json file has",
      "WARNING04": "been created as a placeholder.",
      "WARNING05": "",
      "WARNING06": "If OmniSharp is currently unable to load your project, you can attempt to resolve",
      "WARNING07": "this by restoring any missing project dependencies (example: run 'dotnet restore')",
      "WARNING08": "and by fixing any reported errors from building the projects in your workspace.",
      "WARNING09": "If this allows OmniSharp to now load your project then --",
      "WARNING10": "  * Delete this file",
      "WARNING11": "  * Open the Visual Studio Code command palette (View->Command Palette)",
      "WARNING12": "  * run the command: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'.",
      "WARNING13": "",
      "WARNING14": "If your project requires a more complex launch configuration, you may wish to delete",
      "WARNING15": "this configuration and pick a different template using the 'Add Configuration...'",
      "WARNING16": "button at the bottom of this file.",
      "WARNING17": "*********************************************************************************",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
      "args": ["link"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal repeatable example?

Answer (score 24):

#### The easy way

In VS Code, after you've loaded the code base. Bring up the [command pallet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and enter `> .NET Generate Assets for Build and Debug` then hit return/enter.

This will force VS Code to recreate the `launch.json` and `task.json` files.

Keep an eye on the lower-left corner of the VS Code window for a toast message which looks like this:

[image: screenshot of VS Code showing a toast message asking for confirmation when recreating build and debug assets]

and ensure that you click `Yes`

#### The complicated way

You need to alter the line in your `task.json` file which currently reads:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
```

replacing `<insert-target-framework-here>` with the target framework moniker in your csproj, which might look like something similar to this:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

You'll also need to replace the `<insert-project-name-here>.dll` string with the name of your produced DLL.

Comment: I get the following message ''Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated'' after selecting that Generate Assets for Build and Debug option... :S

Comment: I don't have any task.json file so what do I do?

Comment: @JoyFulCode You need to restart VS Code, it'll work then.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the extension .NET Extension Pack in Visual Studio Code before typing the command '.NET Generate Assets for Build and Debug'

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and Jamie Taylor's answer did not do it for me from the start, it kept saying ''could not find the task 'build'", I can't comment on his answer so here is what worked for me.

**Short answer**
Delete any .vscode folder in your solution root, recursively, if any, before calling `> .NET Generate Assets for Build and Debug`.

**Long answer**
I looked for the first error each time in the OmniSharp Logs (in Output Pane, OmniSharpLog dropdown):

- first error for me was [fail]: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'

  - solution => `mkdir C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\`
- then the next failure was about Omnisharp having trouble restoring my nuget packages

  - solution => cd to the folder where my .sln is and called `dotnet restore`

No more failures in OmniSharp logs, but it still complains about the build task. In my case, I noticed I had two .vscode folders, one at the root, one in another folder in my solution:
 - deleted all of them
 - called `> .NET Generate Assets for Build and Debug`
which did the trick and saw it correctly created `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

Now I can debug correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound weird, but in my case after updating my Visual Studio Code when I hit **Ctrl + Shift + B** the  build action took place successfully.

Answer (score -1):

On visual studio you can use a c# extension's generator to build a launch.json and task.json
However, you also should use the C# extension's generator for launch.json and tasks.json. 
Read this : [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md#3-add-vs-code-configuration-files-to-the-workspace) to do this.
However if you're a beginner on c#, it should be better to use visual studio. All tools are integreted. It's not an edit text but an IDE.
But if you prefer visual studio code, read the doc I've send :).
[visual studio ide](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/)