# Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I just started learning C# a couple hours ago, but have since run into this error.

Ctrl + Shift + P

> .NET:Generate Assets for Build and Debug

But when I click it, an error pops up bottom right of the window:

*Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated.*

Comment: That questions and multiple different answers (which none of helped in my case) shows that while VS Code looks great **it still lacks default support for very basic scenarios**. Configuring debug should be something which is to be resolved by VS Code automatically without requiring me to go through multiple QAs and documentation. I **do not want to know anything about launch.json etc.** until I came to the point I am personally interested in tuning debug configuration a little.

Answer (score 27):

Restarting VS Code solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 14):

This same thing started happening to me on my mac on vscode. For me, it was because I didn't add my dotnet project to my solution file after I created the solution file and project.

This is essentially how I created my project:

1. Create empty project folder `mkdir RecipeApp && cd RecipeApp`
2. Add Solution File to Project (uses the name of containing folder) `dotnet new sln`
3. Create Backend .NET API `dotnet new webapi -o API`

Then this is the part I forgot to do (which actually solved a few other problems I was having, like I couldn't use the `CMD + .` feature to auto import classes and assets etc, too):

4. Add the sub project to the solution file `dotnet sln add API`

After I added the API subproject to the solution file, I could open the main top level project folder in vscode, and everything started working again.

Comment: ugh, totally forgot about this step too haha. Thanks for this

Comment: Fixed it for me as well, thanks

Comment: Had the same issue. Did not need to create something outside of my project folder, a simple `dotnet new sln` followed `dotnet sln add .` did the trick for me (macOS)

Comment: @Dynalon, I like having my solution outside the dotnet project folder, so if I want to create multiple dotnet projects (one for API, one for Tests, etc), the dotnet projects can all easily reference each other, in an organized way, if they are all part of the same solution in this way. I wouldn't say my way is necessarily correct, it's just how I like doing it. 
Thank you for adding your comment, I think it will add value for many.

Answer (score 3):

This issue could be because the `launch.json`, which ideally should have been populated with the necessary details isn't generated in case. This [issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3087) seems to be linked to Omnisharp. If you go through the issue, you understand the root cause more clearly. You may need to perform the steps mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2509#issuecomment-420318250) to get around the issue. These steps involve re-configuring the C# extension inside of your VS Code instance.

Alternately, ensure that all the folders which the extensions uses have appropriate access.

If the issue is also involving `task.json`, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56898897/5253437)

Comment: for me it helped to open the project with opening project_name.csproj with vs-code instead of loading the folder after I configured 'task.json'

Answer (score 3):

In my way helped to change the folder name to a name without spaces.

Comment: Please consider putting this answer in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Changing extension path manually helped me

Answer (score 2):

This happened when I had multiple C# projects and solutions in the directory. What I had to do was to open the command palette by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` and execute `Omnisharp: Select Project`. After choosing the right project, VS Code offered me the assets generation automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out I had the wrong .Net extension dowbloaded. Make sure you download the .Net Core tools extension. After I downloaded that, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently and to resolve it I installed C# Dev Kit and I switched to pre-release version v0.4.6. I couldn't generate debug files with C# extension. .NET sdk was 8 preview

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by installing the C# Dev Kit extension

Then found this article:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging

where the 'No launch.json' scenario helped me further creating an automatic debug configuration.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran

```
dotnet new sln
```

and then

```
dotnet sln add .
```

in the terminal like another reply said and it fixed for me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend doing is pressing "Run" then start debugging, which should open up a launch.json. If you open it, it will have about 17 warnings and then you can delete the warnings. Then, you press f5, which will give you an option to open a tasks.json. Do that and configure all of the tasks for running your project and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

for me it helped to open the project with opening `project_name.csproj` with vs-code instead of loading the folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just uninstall the c# extension and reload the vscode, after I install again (The vscode will ask to install some assets and somethings that miss in the project too).

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on Unity too, and I finally I solved it by downgrading  C# to any version lower than 2.0 this way I'm using Omnisharp instead of the C# extension.
To downgrade an extension click the little arrow on the left of uninstall button.
It also helped to uninstall from the package manager in Unity the visual studio code extension.
Even though I still get an error asking me to upgrade C# extension. I still get intellisense and Omnisharp commands when pressing Ctrl+P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you may not have an active solution, may be it is the solution which is opened as a folder. so the thing to do is

1. Ctrl+Shift+p -> .Net: Open Solution.
2. Ctrl+Shift+p -> .Net: Generate Asset for build and debug

- this will list out the csproj available in the solution.
  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've found just removing all other projects from the explorer and having only the project you want to generate the assets for loaded seems to work. This even works for generating multiple different assets for different projects under the same solution.

Reading through the above, I think it could be an issue with VSCode not being able to interpret which project you want to generate the assets for.