# Could not locate .NET Core Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am following a brackeys tutorial for c# [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N775KsWQVkw). But at 7:55, A message pops up for me saying: "Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated.". I have done everything brackeys did before that moment, but it won't work. Here is an image of the popup:

[image: popup of error]

Any help would be appreciated! Also, do not hesitate to ask for any clarification from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Uninstall the C# extension in VSCode
2. Ctrl+Shift+P `Extensions: Disable Auto Updating Extensions [Enter]`
3. Ctrl+Shift+P `Extensions: Install from VSIX... [Enter]`
4. Reload VSCode

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/issues-dotnet-core-visual-studio-code/

"To fix it, in your VSCode settings, set the OmniSharp Path to latest"

```
{
  "omnisharp.path": "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio Code.
- Open the folder that contains the project you are trying to compile/use.
- Delete the .vscode folder. (Make a backup if needed of any important files/configurations made already.)
- Open the folder in VSCode now.
- Open VSCode Command Palette and choose > .NET: Generate Assets For
  Build and Debug.

Answer (score 0):

As [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362319/could-not-locate-net-core-project-assets-were-not-generated) have commented on another question and on this page, restarting Visual Studio Code usually solves the problem.
This is caused by the c# for Visual Studio Code extension.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the vscode application solved my issue.