# Error when attempting to generate assets in C#: "Could not locate .NET Core project in task1. Assets were not generated."

Tags: c#, .net-core

In Visual Studio Code I Cannot generate C# assets to build and debug because I get the error shown in the title. This was literally working yesterday perfectly fine. I have looked on all forums and videos that had this issue but no matter what I try this error keeps coming back. Maybe I am doing it wrong, some guidance would be very much appreciated. I have downloaded dotnet-sdk-7.0 and 6.0 as that is what University wants me to use.

I tried changing Omnisharp SDK path (but I dont know if that actually did anything), restarting VSC doesn't do anything, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67931494), tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65524003/22357602) (with this one I try to do the 3rd step but it shows me that there are no VSIX files to install from), uninstalled and reinstalled C# to no avail, the only thing I haven't tried is reinstalling VSC, but I'm not sure if that is going to do anything so I will leave it as the *last* thing I do if nothing else works.

This is what happens when I type in "dotnet new console --framework net6.0 --use-program-main --force" in the terminal to create the initial folders and such [as of time of writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCIEv.png)

I was expecting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI1g8.png)
(here I have a .vscode file because I was able to generate the necessary files. Like I said I literally did this exact same process yesterday and it was working fine). I am missing the "bin" folder, so from what I understand everything hasn't been fully initialized and is causing complications?

Again I may not be doing these steps right so I hope someone could help me, If there is anything else that you need to know from me please let me know and I will try my best to explain.