# Visual Studio Code Not Running Default C# Console App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

So, default program built with `dotnet new console -o app`, doesn't run in Visual Studio Code.

Got the .NET SDK installed, and the C# extension.

When I try to add a configuration for it, I get this garbled rubbish.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "WARNING01": "*********************************************************************************",
            "WARNING02": "The C# extension was unable to automatically decode projects in the current",
            "WARNING03": "workspace to create a runnable launch.json file. A template launch.json file has",
            "WARNING04": "been created as a placeholder.",
            "WARNING05": "",
            "WARNING06": "If OmniSharp is currently unable to load your project, you can attempt to resolve",
            "WARNING07": "this by restoring any missing project dependencies (example: run 'dotnet restore')",
            "WARNING08": "and by fixing any reported errors from building the projects in your workspace.",
            "WARNING09": "If this allows OmniSharp to now load your project then --",
            "WARNING10": "  * Delete this file",
            "WARNING11": "  * Open the Visual Studio Code command palette (View->Command Palette)",
            "WARNING12": "  * run the command: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'.",
            "WARNING13": "",
            "WARNING14": "If your project requires a more complex launch configuration, you may wish to delete",
            "WARNING15": "this configuration and pick a different template using the 'Add Configuration...'",
            "WARNING16": "button at the bottom of this file.",
            "WARNING17": "*********************************************************************************",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Bear in mind here, this is a DEFAULT app, built by the program itself, I have changed NOTHING.

It should just print "Hello World!" to the console.

If I try to run from the terminal I get this "Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in...", and when I try to run from the menu bar, I get "Could not find the task 'build'."

If I try to force it, it says it's executed with errors, if I click show errors I get the infinitely helpful "No problems have been detected in the workspace.".

How exactly DO you build a C# console app in VSCode, because it clearly isn't by following Microsoft's own website steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get the message ''could not find the task 'build'" when I try to start my C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893702/i-get-the-message-could-not-find-the-task-build-when-i-try-to-start-my-c-sh)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already done this, and it hasn't helped at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line:

${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/insert-target-framework-here/insert-project-name-here.dll"

You should use the installed framework and the built DLL name instead of these names:
insert-target-framework-here
insert-project-name-here.dll